# Oracle PL/SQL concatenation using wrong variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have a package running on Oracle 11.2.0.3.

```
PROCEDURE LoadEBHSOutputTable (
nSessionId   IN   NUMBER,
dtCstmrSn    IN   VARCHAR2(10),
dtMDS        IN   VARCHAR2(10),
nHrs_Stz     IN   NUMBER,
nSF          IN   NUMBER,
nHB          IN   NUMBER,
sStructConfig in VARCHAR2(30)
)
IS
Icur_id        INTEGER;
Ireturn_rows   INTEGER;
sStmt          VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
Icur_id := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;

sStmt :=
'INSERT INTO rpt_tbl '
|| '(proc_id, cstmr_sn, mds, hrs_stz, svrty_factor, BASELINE_HRS, STRUCT_CFG_ZNE) VALUES   ('
|| nSessionId || ', ' || '''' || dtCstmrSn || '''' || ', ' || '''' || dtMDS || '''' ||   ', ' || nHrs_Stz || ', ' || nSF || ', ' || nHB || ', ' || '''' || replace(sStructConfig,     '''', '''''') || '''' || ')';

DBMS_SQL.parse (Icur_id, sStmt, 1);
Ireturn_rows := DBMS_SQL.execute (Icur_id);

COMMIT;

DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (Icur_id);

END LoadEBHSOutputTable;
```

The value of `nSF` is not being used in the concatenated value assigned to `sStmt` -- it's using the value of `nHB` in its place. In other words, `nHB` appears twice in the set of values in the statement, once for `nSF` (unexpected!) and once for `nHB` (where it should be!).

Guess what "fixes" the problem?

```
IS
Icur_id        INTEGER;
Ireturn_rows   INTEGER;
sStmt          VARCHAR2 (1000);
this_is_dummy_var number;
BEGIN
```

You can add a dummy variable to the proc and suddenly the value of `nSF` is used as intended. Of course, that's not the ideal solution and we're concerned that other places that concatenation is used may be broken in the same way. By the way, this code hasn't been changed in years and suddenly this behavior is observed.

Update 1: another way to "fix" the concatenation is to change `Icur_id` to a NUMBER instead of INTEGER.

**Update 2: We discovered this happening in yet another procedure with concatenation. We figured out that compiling WITHOUT debug fixed it. Re-compiling the same procedure WITH debug reintroduced the concatenation error.**

Comment: Can you post a reproducible test case?  Exactly what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I have to be careful about what values I provide, but I can tell you multiple variations in inputs are reproducing the same concat problem. I queried on v$version and got this: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Any reason why you're doing this procedure using dynamic sql? Is the rpt_tbl being created on the fly?

Comment: We don't need your actual table or your actual data.  Feel free to create a dummy table and dummy data so long as it allows us to reproduce the problem on our machines.

Comment: What happens if you change the definition of `Icur_id` to `NUMBER(38, 0)`? This is what `INTEGER` is defined as in SYS.STANDARD. Also, does it work properly if you use a 'normal' SQL statement, e.g. `INSERT INTO RPT_TBL(proc_id, cstmr_sn, mds, hrs_stz, svrty_factor, BASELINE_HRS, STRUCT_CFG_ZNE) VALUES (nSessionId, dtCstmrSn, dtMDS, nHrs_Stz, nSF, nHB, sStructConfig);`. I don't see why an SQL statement has to be built up and parsed dynamically here.

Comment: Agree 100% this did not need concatenation to work - it's very very old legacy PL/SQL that's just worked all this time.  Please see my update, however, on what we determined to be a better fix than finding all instances of unnecessary concatenation. All packages have been recompiled without debug option.

Answer (score 3):

In my version of Oracle (11.2.0.1.0) I had to remove fields' lengths in procedure's parameters to compile it.

I executed this:

```
exec LoadEBHSOutputTable(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
select * from rpt_tbl;

   PROC_ID CSTMR_SN     MDS       HRS_STZ SVRTY_FACTOR BASELINE_HRS STRUCT_CFG_ZNE 
---------- ------------ ------ ---------- ------------ ------------ ---------------
         1 2            3               4            5            6 7
```

But... maybe You can try approach with template statement replacing all substitutions:

```
sStmt :=
q'[INSERT INTO rpt_tbl (proc_id, cstmr_sn, mds, hrs_stz, svrty_factor, BASELINE_HRS, STRUCT_CFG_ZNE) 
VALUES   ($nSessionId$, '$dtCstmrSn$', '$dtMDS$', $nHrs_Stz$, $nSF$, $nHB$, '$sStructConfig$')]';

sStmt := replace(sStmt,'$nSessionId$',nSessionId);
sStmt := replace(sStmt,'$dtCstmrSn$',dtCstmrSn);
sStmt := replace(sStmt,'$dtMDS$',dtMDS);
sStmt := replace(sStmt,'$nHrs_Stz$',nHrs_Stz);
sStmt := replace(sStmt,'$nSF$',nSF);
sStmt := replace(sStmt,'$nHB$',nHB);
sStmt := replace(sStmt,'$sStructConfig$',replace(sStructConfig,'''', ''''''));
```

I compiled new procedure with above code and the result is:

```
exec LoadEBHSOutputTable2(10,20,30,40,50,60,70);
select * from rpt_tbl;

   PROC_ID CSTMR_SN    MDS       HRS_STZ SVRTY_FACTOR BASELINE_HRS STRUCT_CFG_ZNE
---------- ----------- ------ ---------- ------------ ------------ ----------------
        10 20          30             40           50           60 70
         1 2           3               4            5            6 7
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good catch - I hadn't noticed the VARCHR2 lengths in the procedure definition.

Comment: I'm sorry I misled with the Varchar2(x) variable declarations. I was trying to obscure actual schema. Those variables were declared as a type of a specific column. I substituted in my post with the column type.